Regularity of an elliptical problem
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain with boundary of class $C^{\infty}$, with $N \geq 3$. Moreover, consider the uniformly elliptic operator
$$\mathcal{L}v := -\Delta v - \lambda v.$$
If $u \in H^1_0(\Omega) \cap \left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{r \geq 1} L^r(\Omega)\right)$ is a nonnegative application and weak homogeneous solution $\mathcal{L}u = u^{2^*-1}$ in $\Omega$, where $2^* = 2N/(N-2)$, then $u \in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$?
Note: From the previous conditions, we know that $f := u^{2^* - 1} \in L^2(\Omega)$. Therefore, by the Global Regularity Theorem, we have $u \in W^{2,2}_0(\Omega)$ (see Theorem 8.12 in Gilbarg & Trudinger). However, how do we go on to get $u \in W^{4,2}_0(\Omega)$? and so on? A bootstrap argument doesn't seem functional by the definition of $f$.
